# How to compare the variability of two measures from meta analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, variability

I have two measures from each of 20 studies. Random-effects meta analysis has been performed for each of the two measures, and for each measure I have two values to indicate data variability, cross-study (random effect) variance $\tau^2$ and its chi-square test statistic $Q$. Now I'd like to compare the cross-study variability between the two measures. $\tau^2$ does not seem to be a good choice because it is dimensional (having different units) and carries the same physical meaning as its corresponding measure. Since the chi-square value $Q$ is dimensionless, I was wondering whether I could construct the ratio of the two $Q$ values as a pseudo $F$-statistic (with the numerator and denominator degrees of freedom being the same) to test for equal variability across subjects between the two measures. Or any better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could calculate the ratio of the two $Q$ values as a way of quantifying the comparative variability of the two measures, but it won't have an $F$-distribution as there's no reason to think the numerator and denominator $Q$ values have chi-squared distributions or that they are independent. The only alternative I can think of is bootstrapping the studies and looking at the bootstrap distribution of this ratio, though 20 studies is perhaps a rather small sample size for bootstrapping.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! The two $Q$ values presumably follow chi-square distribution under the random-effects model framework of meta analysis; however, their independence is indeed something that can't be reasonably assumed.